# recurrence criterion for random-walk like Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose we have a random-walk like Markov chain, i.e. state space is the set of all integers from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, the transition probability $P_{ij}$ is nonzero only when $j=i+1$ or $j=i-1$.

The difference from the random walk is that the transition probability is periodic in state space i.e. $P_{i,i+1}=p_1,P_{i+1,i+2}=p_2,\dots,P_{i+L-1,i+L}=p_L,P_{i+L,i+L+1}=p_1$, and none of $p_i$ is 0 or 1.

My question is: under what conditions (in terms of $\{p_i\}$) is this Markov chain recurrent or transient?

Comment: Nice question. (It seems $P_{i+L,i+L+1}=p_1$, not $P_{i+L+1,i+L+2}$.)

Comment: you are right! edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $x$, let $T_x$ denote the first hitting time of $x$. Looking at the chain at its successive visits of multiples of $L$, one sees that there is recurrence if and only if $h_L=\frac12$, where, for $0\leqslant x\leqslant 2L$, 
$$
h_x=P_x(T_{2L}\lt T_0).
$$
The computation of $h_L$ involves the finite Markov chain on $\{0,1,\ldots,2L\}$ hence the standard approach applies, which is as follows.

Let $r_x=r_{x+L}=p_{x+1}$ for $0\leqslant x\leqslant L-1$. By the Markov property, the vector $(h_x)_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 2L}$ solves the linear system 
$$
h_{2L}=1,\quad h_0=0,\quad h_x=r_xh_{x+1}+(1-r_x)h_{x-1}\quad (1\leqslant x\leqslant 2L-1).
$$
The change of variable $h_x=\sum\limits_{y=1}^xk_y$ yields $r_xk_{x+1}=(1-r_x)k_x$ for every $1\leqslant x\leqslant 2L-1$, which is easily solved. The normalization $h_{2L}=1$ yields finally 
$$
h_x=\frac{K_x}{K_{2L}},\qquad
K_x=\sum\limits_{y=1}^xR_{y-1},\qquad R_{y}=\prod_{z=1}^{y}\frac{1-r_z}{r_z}.
$$
Up to this point, this is entirely general and applies to every random walk on the integers with transitions $(r_x)$. We now turn to the specifics of the case at hand.

Due to the periodicity of $(r_x)$, for every $1\leqslant y\leqslant L$, $R_{y+L}=R_LR_y$ hence
$$
K_{2L}-K_L=\sum\limits_{y=L+1}^{2L}R_{y-1}=\sum\limits_{y=1}^{L}R_{y+L}=R_L\sum\limits_{y=1}^{L}R_{y}=R_LK_L,
$$
which yields the simple identity
$$
h_L=\frac1{1+R_L},\qquad
R_L=\prod_{x=1}^L\frac{1-p_x}{p_x}.
$$
This shows that:

- if $R_L=1$, then the chain is null recurrent,
- if $R_L\lt1$, then $h_L\gt\frac12$ hence the chain is transient (and goes to $+\infty$ at linear speed),
- if $R_L\gt1$, then $h_L\lt\frac12$ hence the chain is transient (and goes to $-\infty$ at linear speed).

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? Such as the meaning of $T_L$ and how is the conductance related to the problem?

Comment: See Edit. The new version avoids conductances, due to my laziness. However, to get acquainted with the notion (which explains the result much better than the tedious computations above, if you ask me), one can read the amazing *Random walks and electrical networks* by Doyle and Snell.

Comment: really nice proof!