# recurrence criterion for random-walk like (simple) inhomogeneous Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

This question is to some degree a follow-up of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417443/recurrence-criterion-for-random-walk-like-markov-chain).

Suppose we have a random-walk like Markov chain, i.e. state space is the set of all integers from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, the transition probability $P_{ij}$ is nonzero only when $j=i+1$ or $j=i-1$.

The difference from the random walk is that the transition probability is periodic in state space and periodic in time (for simplicity, let's consider a period 2 case, and hence it is inhomogeneous Markov chain) i.e.

At time $2t$,
$P_{i,i+1}=p_1,P_{i+1,i+2}=p_2,\dots,P_{i+L-1,i+L}=p_L,P_{i+L,i+L+1}=p_1$, and none of $p_i$ is 0 or 1.
At time $2t+1$, $P_{i,i+1}=q_1,P_{i+1,i+2}=q_2,\dots,P_{i+L-1,i+L}=q_L,P_{i+L,i+L+1}=q_1$, and none of $q_i$ is 0 or 1.

My question is: under what conditions (in terms of $\{p_i\}$) is this Markov chain recurrent or transient? (Is this question even meaningful?)

Is it possible to generalize the results to inhomogeneous Markov chain with general finite time period $M$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $Y_n=X_{2n}$. Then $(Y_n)$ is a time-homogenous Markov chain. Its transition probabilities $R_{ij}$ are nonzero only for $j$ in $\{i-2,i,i+2\}$ and they are periodic in the sense that, for every $(i,j)$, $R_{i+L,j+L}=R_{i,j}$. The usual tools apply to $(Y_n)$. Finally, $(X_n)$ is positive recurrent / recurrent null / transient if and only if $(Y_n)$ is.

Comment: What does $R_{i,j}$ mean? And, is the last statement a well-known theorem? What is it called?

Comment: The same as your $P_{i,j}$, only for $(Y_n)$. Last statement: this is common sense (think one second about the paths of $Y$).

Comment: Would you mind showing the "usual tools" to determine whether $Y_n$ is recurrent when, for example, the spatial period is $L=3$, and the time period $M=4$, such that $R_{ij}$ are nonzero for $j$ in $\{i-4,i-2,i,i+2,i+4\}$?

Comment: Since $(Y_n)$ is a time-homogenous Markov chain with state-periodic transitions, I am referring to [the solution to your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/417488/6179) solving this case.